# Web API using Asp.net membership

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-membership

I am in the process of finishing up working on a web API application that is to be used for an android app. Unfortunately, my main website uses asp.net membership database.

I added the old asp.net membership code from my web form program in the Web API to create new users within the membership database and to retrieve the USERID from the newly created entry. This does not work, however. I thought it would work since I did not get any error indicating it would not when the code was added like I did when I added the Profile Common code.

My question are:

1. Will I need to upgrade my old membership to Identity? (Not ideal).
2. Can the asp.net membership database be used with web api? Any examples?

   ```
       Dim status As MembershipCreateStatus

       If Membership.GetUser(newMember.Username) Is Nothing Then

           Membership.CreateUser(newMember.Username, Hash(Password), newMember.Email, "None", "None", True, status)

       End If

   Catch ex As Exception        

   End Try

   Try
       FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newMember.Username, True)
   Catch ex As Exception        


   End Try

   Try

       Dim mbr As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(newMember.Username)
       Membership.UpdateUser(mbr)
       userGUID = mbr.ProviderUserKey

   Catch ex As Exception           

   End Try

   Try
       If Not Roles.IsUserInRole(newMember.Username, "member") Then
           Roles.AddUserToRole(newMember.Username, "member")
       End If
   Catch ex As Exception

   End Try
   Return userGUID
   ```

Comment: You will need to [edit] your question and include the code that doesn't work, because ASP.NET Web API runs on ASP.NET so it fully supports membership

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Added code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The issue was that I needed to use user id and password in the connection string.